# Derivation of dz[1] for backpropagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mathematics

Can anyone mathematically prove this equation given the values of $dz^{[2]}$, $W^{[2]}$, $z^{[1]}$ and the activation function $g^{[1]}$

$dz^{[1]} = w^{[2]T}dz^{[2]} * g^{[1]'}(z^{[1]})$

Answer (score 0):

For the formal proof I think it's best to post on maths stackexchange instead.

Here are one of the best videos on backpropagation:

[(link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=An5z8lR8asY)

[(link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOc_y67AzCA&t=470s)

Your equation shows the chain rule.

- hadamard-multiplying any matrix (like $w^T$) by a vector-with-n-entries (in your case by $dz^{[2]}$) is basically saying "I scale each stripe of my matrix by the corresponding entry in vector $dz$"

regarding the "stripes":

- each row of $W^{[2]}$ represents a weights from **one of our** neurons to all neurons in preceding layer
- each column of $W^{[2]}$ represents weights from **all our neurons** towards one particular neuron in preceding layer.
- your activations ($g$) each depends on the weights that flow into it (the weights are the parameters of these activations).
- your activations also depend on the values of neurons that flow into them. Notice, although neurons are the same entities used by the activations, they are treated **as separate branches** on the tree diagram [(link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCr13iTRN7E&t=4s)

If you watch the "tree diagram link", here is one more hint: in the video, the girl was *summing up* the terms from different branches. This is exactly what the dot product is doing during backprop.